# Rollup svelte - kept calling /json and /json/version every second

Tags: json, svelte, rollup

I have a performance issues when running rollup -c -w command for a svelte app. It keeps calling "/json" and "/json/version" every second. I have add @rollup/plugin-json last night, but didn't really use it. This error came long time after that.  I have no clue why this happens. I have also uninstalled @rollup/plugin-json, but nothing solved. It does not look related.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxOiW.png)

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the JSON plugin since you're getting actual HTTP requests. It sounds like it could be DevTools trying to connect to your server, see nodejs discussions on a similar issue: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1444 and https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18606.

Comment: This is exactly it. I was trying to use chrome://inspect . Disconnecting the devTools solved that. Seeing that this is called every second stressed me, considering the heating effect of node on my laptop!